# how do I create unique constraints on two properties in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm using nodes as intermediate path elements, but I want to make sure the start/end are unique. How do I create a constraint that requires TWO values to be checked?

I can set individual ones but can't see syntax for a two-part constraint.

```
        neolib.run_query(
            """CREATE CONSTRAINT
                uSource
                if not exists
                ON (m:route) ASSERT m.source IS UNIQUE""")
        neolib.run_query(
            """CREATE CONSTRAINT
            uTarget
            if not exists
            ON (m:route) ASSERT m.target IS UNIQUE""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has this documentation:

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/constraints/#query-constraint-node-key

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT [constraint_name] [IF NOT EXISTS]
ON (n:LabelName)
ASSERT (n.propertyName_1,
n.propertyName_2,
…
n.propertyName_n)
IS NODE KEY
[OPTIONS "{" option: value[, ...] "}"]

FOR EXAMPLE:
    CREATE CONSTRAINT uSourceTarget IF NOT EXISTS ON (m:route) ASSERT (m.source, m. target) IS NODE KEY
```

NB: Only applicable for Enterprise Edition (NOT community edition)

Comment: got it, so `node KEY` constraint rather than normal node constraint.

Comment: yes, it is. Please accept my answer (check button) if it works. Thanks.